# How to include VSIX output in it's package?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix

I have created a VSIX package and I want to include it's output dll in the VSIX, I have tried adding MEF component refrencing to itself in vsixmanifest file in Assets section, but it doesn't resolved. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your project file with notepad and set this items to true

```
<IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>
<IncludeDebugSymbolsInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeDebugSymbolsInVSIXContainer>
<IncludeDebugSymbolsInLocalVSIXDeployment>true</IncludeDebugSymbolsInLocalVSIXDeployment>
<CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>true</CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>
<CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>true</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>
```